# ブロックリストとは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案, ブロックリスト

このサイトの「ブロックリスト」とは何のことで、どのような機能が有りますか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 3):

ブロックリストとは、質問や回答が投稿される前に内容をチェックする仕組みです。

Stack Exchangeサイト群の全てに適用される全体設定と、それぞれのサイトに適用される固有の設定とがあります。サイト固有の設定の一部はそのサイトのモデレーターにより閲覧できます。完全な情報へのアクセスと設定の変更はStack Exchange社のみが可能です。

#### 設定できるチェック項目

- 対象

  - タグ
  - 本文
  - タイトル
- 条件

  - 正規表現によるマッチ
  - 予め定められている「タグが無い」などの状態
- 条件に該当した際の動作

  - 警告: 投稿画面にヒントを表示します
  - ブロック: 指摘内容を修正しないと投稿できません
- メッセージ
  警告やブロック時に表示される文字列で、リンクなどのHTML要素も使用できます

メタサイトとメインサイトは、それぞれ別に設定を持っています。

#### 参考

情報がまとめられたドキュメントは無いようです。Meta Stack Exchangeには[「blocklist」タグが付けられた質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocklist)が有りますので参考にして下さい。